# What happens to my position if I hold some stocks of a company that gets acquired?

Tags: stocks, corporate-acquisition

Say I have some stocks of company A, and I didn't issue any orders on my trading platform. Some day, company B acquired company A. What would happen to me?

Am I totally out of control for the price? Will the money be automatically refunded into my account of my trading platform?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The stockholders of company A vote to approve or disapprove the buy out. That is the only control you have on the price: Vote to approve or disapprove.

If the deal is approved then you get the money, or stock in B, or both, in accordance with the terms of the deal. It will arrive into your account automatically.

Comment: I have very few stocks, can I still vote? If so, how? Is there a "vote button" in the trading platforms? Thanks

Comment: The way it works for me is that I receive an email from my broker and the email contains a link to a voting page. The same thing is done annually to vote at the stockholders meeting.

Comment: @AGamePlayer if you only have a few shares, then the major shareholders will make the decision anyway, whether you vote or not.